# Understanding the warning "comparison of promoted ~unsigned with unsigned"

Tags: c, gcc

I've encountered a warning that I don't really understand. The warning is generated by comparing what I consider to be one unsigned with another unsigned.

Here is the source:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t *arr = malloc(8);
    assert(arr);

    /* fill arr[] with stuff */

    if (arr[3] != (uint8_t)(~arr[2])) { // Warning is here
        /* stuff */
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which I build using the following procedure:

```
user@linux:~ $ gcc -o test -Wall -Wextra test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:13:16: warning: comparison of promoted ~unsigned with unsigned [-Wsign-compare]
```

I'm using gcc version 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)

How can I fix the above comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I think its a bug. Read [[Bug c/38341] Wrong warning comparison of promoted ~unsigned with unsigned](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2008-12/msg00046.html) and also [Why, warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/zqkxTTVCvDA). This might help you.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I worked around it by using an intermediate variable:

```
uint8_t check = ~arr[2];
if (arr[3] != check)
```