# How to compare a complement in C without to have compiler warning?

Tags: c, gcc

I want to check if a complement of a variable is correct. 
I have written the following snippet of code.

```
static U8 act_cntr_cpl
if(act_cntr_cpl == (U8)(~act_cntr))
```

but the compiler throws the following warning :

```
 comparison of promoted ~unsigned with unsigned [-Werror=sign-compare]
```

I cannot understand where is the problem and why the compiler does not like this. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `act_cntr`

Comment: And what is `U8`?

Comment: irrelevant and unsigned 8 bit (char), fairly obvious wouldn't you say?

Comment: Have you tried putting the tilde on the outside of the arrangement?

Comment: @poprock Please show a MVCE. Otherwise, everything is a guess.

Comment: Hmm. This behaviour appears to be [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447210/understanding-the-warning-comparison-of-promoted-unsigned-with-unsigned).